# SSAS Processing Slow - SQL Server 2012

Tags: performance, ssas, ssas-2012

I have two SQL Server Agent jobs that run XMLA to process SSAS objects in a SQL 2012 SSAS server.
**ProcessCubeFull** This runs after the related SQL database has been reloaded from scratch, this is a weekly job. This job does the following:
1. Process Dimensions, ProcessFull, uses  MaxParallel="4", Time: **20 minutes**
2. Process Partitions, ProcessFull, uses  MaxParallel="4", Time: **85 minutes**
3. Process Cubes, ProcessFull, uses  MaxParallel="4", Time: **100 minutes**

**ProcessCubeUpdate** This runs after the related SQL database had its daily update, this is a daily job. This job does the following:
1. Process Dimensions, ProcessUpdate, uses  MaxParallel="4",Time: **100 minutes**
2. Process Partitions, ProcessData, uses  MaxParallel="4", ,Time: **15 minutes**
3. Process Indexes, ProcessIndexes, uses  MaxParallel="4", Time: **55 minutes**
4. Processes Cubes, ProcessDefault, uses  MaxParallel="4", Time: **1 minute**

The performance of these jobs is very slow and getting slower. 
It also seems odd that for the dimensions ProcessFull is a lot faster than ProcessUpdate.

I would like to know how I can speed these jobs up, or if they need some additional steps?

Answer (score 2):

If your processing time is reasonable from your data size, I suggest you use multiple partitions for your objects

Comment: Thank you, that certainly looks like something worth investigating.